# PC Minecraft World-Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, discord

So I got minecraft on PC about a year ago and I never really haven gotten to play it until now. I joined Mineplex and wondered in my mind, 'Can I turn my world into a server?'. I looked it up and google didnt really help. If i cant, then is there a way for me to create a world, and copy a certain link to put in my discord server so other people can play?

Conclusion: I want to turn an ordinary world that I created into a server without having to pay or at least a world that i can play with other people.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, if you are on Java edition you can indeed turn your world into a server for free! This also works for Bedrock edition, although I don't know much about that.

If you have anymore questions about this, or your playing on java edition and need help setting up a server, feel free to ask me!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121221/discussion-on-answer-by-crazed-pc-minecraft-world-minecraft-server).